# android Filtered Product QTY and View update

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am using `listView.setOnItemClickListener` in adapter  to open a popup to update product QTY, when user press OK and QTY > 0 then call a listener in activity. This way model and view have been updated properly. But when I use FilterResults to filter Product then  update product QTY It shows QTY, Next I search same product from actionbar search I am getting product QTY 0.

Here is my code

```
private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                results.values = originalData;
                results.count = originalData.size();

            }else{
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                final List<Product> list = originalData;
                int count = list.size();
                final ArrayList<Product> filterlist = new ArrayList<Product>(count);

                for (Product product:list) {
                    String productCode          =  product.getProductCode();
                    String productName          =  product.getProductName() ;
                   // String genericName            =  product.getGenericName() ;
                    String packSize             =  product.getPackSize() ;
                    String unitTp               =  product.getUnitTp();
                    String unitVat              =  product.getUnitVat();
                    String updQty               =  product.getQty() != null ? product.getQty() : "0";

                    Product model = new Product(productCode, productName, null, packSize, unitTp, unitVat, updQty, null,null)  ;

                    if (productName.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                        filterlist.add(model);
                    }
                }
                results.values = filterlist;
                results.count = filterlist.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<Product>) results.values;
            OrderDetailsAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you try to change item QTY from filtered result you are missing to update same item of `originalData`

Comment: after filter a product  I changed  qty using click on list item  and call updatelListener to update model.

Comment: After clear the search input and again search same product but QTY getting 0

Comment: View is updated when view holder QTY text changed by filter

Comment: `call updatelListener to update model` you mean main module ie `originalData` right?

Comment: Property Model  has changed QTY but view holder is not updated when search same product

Comment: have you called `notifyDataSetChanged();` after changing QTY.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged()  called in activity where I implemented updatelListener method